# Sum different range of columns per row

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sum, row

I would like to create a new variable in my dataset that sums a certain range of columns, however the range of columns to sum varies for each row.

Here is my sample dataset. I want to create a new variable, `NUM1` that is the sum of the columns 1 to `ARRAYEND`, where the variable `ARRAYEND` specifies what column `NUM1` should sum up to.

```
#create sample dataset
r1<-c(1,1,1,1,0,2)
r2<-c(1,1,0,1,1,4)
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2))
names(df)<-c("Flag1","Flag2","Flag3","Flag4","Flag5","ARRAYEND")

   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 ARRAYEND
r1     1     1     1     1     0        2
r2     1     1     0     1     1        4
```

This is the result I want:

```
  Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 ARRAYEND NUM1
r1     1     1     1     1     0        2    2
r2     1     1     0     1     1        4    3
```

I tried to do this through `dplyr` , but it is giving me an error.

```
df <-df %>% mutate(NUM1 = rowSums(.[1:df$ARRAYEND]))

Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `NUM1`.
ℹ numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
ℹ Input `NUM1` is `rowSums(.[1:df$ARRAYEND])`. 
2: In 1:df$ARRAYEND :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to loop over the rows with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1`, then get the `seq`uence of 'ARRAYEND', subset the elements of 'x' and get the `sum`

```
df$NUM1 <- apply(df, 1, function(x)  sum(x[seq(x['ARRAYEND'])]))
```

-output

```
df
#   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 ARRAYEND NUM1
#r1     1     1     1     1     0        2    2
#r2     1     1     0     1     1        4    3
```

NOTE: `tidyverse` doesn't keep the rownames.  So, it may be better to use `base R`

---

if we want `tidyverse`, an option is to get the rownames as a column first

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(NUM1 = sum(c_across(starts_with("Flag"))[seq(ARRAYEND)])) %>%    
    ungroup %>%
    column_to_rownames('rn')
```

-output

```
#   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 ARRAYEND NUM1
#r1     1     1     1     1     0        2    2
#r2     1     1     0     1     1        4    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `Reduce`

```
transform(
  df,
  NUM1 = list2DF(Reduce("+", df, accumulate = TRUE))[cbind(seq_along(ARRAYEND), ARRAYEND)]
)
```

gives

```
   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 ARRAYEND NUM1
r1     1     1     1     1     0        2    2
r2     1     1     0     1     1        4    3
```